# How to use auto layout so my app fits all screen sizes in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I need my buttons to stay in the same positions for all phones.

I want it to look like this on all iPhones:

[image]

But when I switch to a larger size phone it does this, it also looks ugly on smaller phones as well:

[image]

Comment: Please add details of what you have tried.

Comment: I think you must read some documents about AutoLayout

Answer (score 0):

That is a VERY broad question, as a lot of iOS UI depends on autolayout.  I suggest you work through these tuts at at least [AutoLayout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2).  From your screen shots, it looks as if you have set a width constraint on your view with the green background instead of pinning the leading, trailing, top, and bottom to the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout is, in essence, a system that performs calculations based on constraints. This means that to perform what you want, you need to add constraints to each of your objects so that the compiler knows how you want to resize your UI. But like others have said, that is a very general question. I suggest looking into the topic a bit before asking, so you can narrow down your question and get better answers.

Comment: My buttons get rearranged in other phone sizes

Comment: That's because you aren't implementing your constraints correctly. If you can't do something like add constraints to a UI, you shouldn't be developing an app yet.

Comment: So how do I figure out how to do so? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define positions for all your button or views. You need to define atleast 4 constraints for all your view. By adding constraints you tell your views where they should be placed on all screens. You define their positioning with respect to screen by adding constraints.

When you add trailing, from top and width and height constraint you tell that view should be placed in fixed position i.e. x , y and occupy defined space whatever may be screen size.You can opt for fixed width or height. Instead of fixing height and width you can also define leading or trailing constraints for the view. Constraints will adjust views frame according to screen size.

For beginning you can opt for some tutorials available online. You can check Raywanderlich [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2). Hope it helps.

Comment: When I add the constraints it has the red lines though, in addition all the screen sizes don't have the same amount of pixels, so the fixed positions won't work?....or will they?